# Finding elements in a finite bijective set

Tags: functions

**The Question:**

> Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and let $X = \{f|f : A → A \text{ is a bijection}\}$. List the elements of $X$ and given them each names. (Hint: there are $6$.)

**My Thoughts**

I think I can get $3$ of them by mapping the values onto themselves, but then how would I get the other values?

Comment: Do you know about groups and permutation groups ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the symmetry group of three elements. You can read up on these groups [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group). 
I like to write the set $X=\{Id, T_1, T_2, T_3, R, R^2 \}$. I will write three elements below and leave the rest to you.

Id:  Which is the identity element. It leaves all the elements where they are.

$1 \to 1$

$2 \to 2$

$3 \to 3$

$T_1:$ Which Transposes $2$ and $3$ and leaves $1$ fixed. You can guess what is meant by $T_2$ and $T_3$ by examining this guy.

$1 \to 1$

$2 \to 3$

$3 \to 2$

$R: $ Who rotates all the elements. $R^2$ is the result of applying $R$ twice.

$1 \to 2$

$2 \to 3$

$3 \to 1$

Answer (score 0):

If $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ is a permutation of $(1,2,3)$.

We can let $f_p(i)=p_i$.

There are $3!$ permutations of $(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of what a bijective function does. Each element in the domain maps uniquely to one element of the codomain, and each element of the codomain will have a preimage.

It might be best to make a tree diagram or something of the sort if you're not familiar with permutation groups or such. Of the three elements you can map the element $1$ to, you pick one of them in the first branch. In each branch, you're left with two different options for which to map $2$ to (you cannot map to what you map $1$ to because it won't be injective), and in the final branch only one option to map $3$ to. Once you have that all figured out, you should be able to follow the paths in tree diagram to find your definition for a bijective $f$.